# How to type-erase a C++ concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to implement a small networking library to learn about concepts and I'm trying to find a way to define succinct concepts without having to carry template parameters over dependent concepts. For instance, I have the following concepts:

```
template <typename ValueT>
concept bool Value = true;

template <typename BufferT>
concept bool Buffer = requires(BufferT buf)
{
    { buf.Size() } -> std::size_t;
    { buf.Capacity() } -> std::size_t;
    { buf.Put(Value</* How can I resolve this to any value */>) } -> bool;
    { buf.Take(Value</* How can I resolve this to any value */>) } -> bool;
};

template <typename ReadableT>
concept bool Readable = requires(ReadableT r)
{
    { r.Read(Buffer</* How can I resolve this to any buffer */>) } -> void;
};

template <typename WritableT>
concept bool Writable = requires(WritableT w)
{
    { w.Write(Buffer</* How can I resolve this to any buffer */>) } -> void;
};

template <typename ChannelT>
concept bool Channel = requires(ChannelT chan)
{
    requires Readable<ChannelT>;
    requires Writable<ChannelT>;
};
```

How can I define the `Value` and `Buffer` concepts without having to explicitly have a template parameter? Is it even possible? I would intuitively write it this way:

```
template <typename ReadableT>
concept bool Readable = requires(ReadableT r)
{
    template <typename ValueT> 
    { r.Read(Buffer<ValueT>) } -> void;
};
```

But this doesn't compile (obviously) and I can't figure out the right syntax.

**EDIT**: I have a feeling the right syntax is like so:

```
template <typename BufferT>
concept bool Buffer = requires(BufferT buf, Value val)
{
    { buf.Size() } -> std::size_t;
    { buf.Capacity() } -> std::size_t;
    { buf.Put(val) } -> bool;
    { buf.Take(val) } -> bool;
};
```

But GCC (8.3.0) prints this message:

```
internal compiler error: in synthesize_implicit_template_parm, at cp/parser.c:39141
    concept bool Buffer = requires(BufferT buf, Value val)
                                             ^~~~~
Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

Comment: "*internal compiler error*" That always means your compiler broke.

Comment: Are you saying that you want `Buffer` to be a think you can put *any value* into? That you can pass it any object of any type, and this somehow has to work? Are you *sure* that's what you want?

Comment: @NicolBolas For now yes, eventually I'll constrain it, but the idea is that I should be able to put any struct, or an integer or a string, or anything really in a buffer. From the point of view of the channel though, it doesn't care what values have been put in the buffer; it just wants to keep a reference to it, to eventually call `writev` with all the data. So a channel should be configurable with any buffers, and its concept should be agnostic of buffers or values. Yet, I can't type erase ValueT or BufferT from channels which make the syntax really cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

> the idea is that I should be able to put any struct, or an integer or a string, or anything really in a buffer

That is not a question that a concept is capable of answering. Nor is it meant to.

Concepts are meant to constrain templates. And a template is supposed to, on some level, know what it is doing. A specific template instantiation doesn't work on "any struct, or an integer or a string"; it works on *specific types*, defined by its template arguments and expressions dependent on them. The same goes for a concept.

So consider a template like this:

```
template<typename Buff, typename Iterator>
void InsertIntoBuffer(Buff &buf, Iterator beg, Iterator ed)
{
  for(; beg != ed; ++beg)
    buf.Put(*beg);
}
```

The constraint this function wants to put on `Buff` is *not* "has a `Put` function that can take any object." The actual constraint is "has a `Put` function that can take what `Iterator`'s `operator*` returns."

So "putting" and "taking" is not just a constraint on `Buff`; it also needs to know what is being "put" or "taken".

To put it another way, it isn't the type that has a constraint; it's the *operation* as a whole which is constrained.

So you would have a base constraint for `Buffer`, which is a thing with size and capacity. But you should also have a `PutBuffer` constraint which imposes the requirement that `Buffer` can `Put` the given type.

Similarly, a `Readable` is really a `ReadableFromBuffer`, where the buffer type is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have an unbounded family of constraints on a type—that it support `put(int)`, `put(int*)`, `put(int**)`, *etc.*, for example.  (How would such a constraint be checked, in general?)  And you really don’t want to claim that a template `put` exists that can take *any* `T`, because while the (traditional, unconstrained) syntax suggests that it can, there are almost always implicit constraints (or assumptions) that would be broken by instantiating with *some* `T` (consider abstruse things like `void() const`).

As a practical matter for serialization, you could just check that `put` accepts `int`, `float`, and `const char*`, perhaps along with a representative `std::vector` or so.